# Potassium tert-butoxide reaction with chloroform and picric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

If potassium tert-butoxide is used in a solution of chloroform and and a strong protic acid like picric acid will the tert-butoxide ion react with picric acid or will it form a dichlorocarbene.

Mechanism for reactions will be much appreciated.

(This is most definitely NOT a homework question! 
I need to know this to solve my homework problems)

Comment: Well, in both cases, KOtBu acts as a base. If you were a molecule of KOtBu, would you prefer to react with CHCl3 or picric acid?

Comment: @orthocresol from what I know, I would react with picric acid because it has a pKa of around .38 ( I think?), much lower than that of chloroform. But I wanted to know if there was some other mechanism that I wasn't aware of which would force it to react with CHCl3 to form a dichlorocarbene.

Comment: Depends if you had more equivalents of KOtBu than picric acid.Even if you have some chloroform deprotonation, the protonation from picric acid is so much faster than loss of Cl-.